# Java framework for desktop application development

Tags: java, frameworks, desktop-application

Due to some constraints in the project I'm working on, I need to develop a desktop application using Java. Now, I face the decision of which framework should I use. Is there any outstanding one? I've searched in different questions already done in this forum, but most of them are from 2014 or earlier.

Comment: Java is cross platform, doesn't matter what framework you talk about. Google Java FX

Comment: You should try javafx

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is a useful question and shouldn't have been closed, in my opinion. The boilerplate statement that this sort of question attracts 'opinionated answers and spam' is simply untrue. Every time I look at a question like this I find useful answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @StephaneM told this is off topic. Anyways you should use javaFX. Which is a library that has graphics and media controlling capabilities. Your next question would be what kind of IDE you should use. As I have seen both Eclipse and Intellij Idea have the drag and drop UI building interfaces. So you can only focus on the functionality building. Welcome to Stackoverflow and please read what @StephaneM mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JavaFx. You can also find a lot of tutorials on JavaFx in google.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm